# AEM session object not garbaged collected

Tags: java, session, garbage-collection, session-timeout, aem

For the past month I've been dealing with a AEM 6.0 production site that after a week or so needs a restart of the instance. In this particular case it is my publisher that is failing. So I looked into it further more and found that everything works great at first then after a few days the garbage collection goes crazy so CPU utilization increases like crazy. From there I restarted my publisher and waited to get a heap dump when the GC went wacky again and analysed it with MAT (Memory Analyser Tool from eclipse). After my inspection I found that 94 % of the heap is occupied by a ConcurrentHashMap. I dove into that object and found that Sessions are the issue at hand or at least one of the main problems. The session-timeout value is 0, so no timeout on sessions. My error logs shows this type of message:

```
*WARN* [ip [1432319636774] GET something HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.RefreshStrategy This session has been idle for 2 minutes and might be out of date. Consider using a fresh session or explicitly refresh the session.
```

Is it possible to configure the session manager in AEM ?
Has anyone seen this in AEM before ?
Should I set the session-timeout to 1 or some value in particular ?
Any suggestions would be welcome to know how I should proceed to solve this issue ?

### Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what AEM is? What type of environment is it? If a servlet environment timeout would probably be in minutes

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Oak issue, which was mostly fixed with Oak 1.0.12. Consider installing service pack 2 for AEM 6.0 with the latest hotfixes on top of it if possible. You should plan also some migration time if you have lib overlays, but the effort for updating in comparison to the daily troubles caused by the software is minimal. You can find the [latest AEM hotfixes here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem6-available-hotfixes.html) or in the [package share](http://localhost:4502/crx/packageshare/index.html).

If you can't install service pack 2, than consider installing all available Oak hotfixes. There are also several new oak:index packages you need to install.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I updated to SP2 and oak 1.0.12 a while ago and that did not do anything to solve my problem. I recently updated to oak 1.0.13 but the same problem is still present. All hotfixes are installed as well. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Ok this mean that you may have some not properly handled sessions in your code. It's worth to check your code, fix them as [my example shows in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29671758/777679) and check again if the problem is still there. I can remember that AEM 6 had such problem with the asset finder, but it was solved with some of the lot hotfixes already.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I had a look at your example and it doesn't seem to be our problem still baffled by this issue. If you have any other ideas I'll gladly take a look at them. In any case thanks again for the help d33t.

Comment: It's hard to tell you the exact reason without having the system in front of me. Even than it's not easy and it is a very time consuming task. What you can do next is to check once again your code, if you don't find anything, than try to reproduce the issue on a vanity system and report the bug to daycare.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it's exactly what we've been doing, we just submitted a report to daycare. Once I get more information I'll make sure to update everyone on the situation. Thanks again !

Comment: I was wondering if there is any solution from Daycare on the above?